# How to scroll an iframe to the bottom when page loads?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I was like on every question about this on the net, tried like 50 diff methods, first i tried to scroll the div - then when its not worked i've tried to iframe the file with the div and scroll the iframe.. nothing just works!

Look on the last script i have set up:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = 100; //arbitrary time in ms
$("#frame").animate({ scrollTop: $("#frame").height()}, t);
});
</script>

<center><iframe id="frame" src="xxx.php" frameborder="0" width="630px" height="500px"></iframe></center>
```

I tried both #frame and frame without the (#), both with (document).ready and without it.
Nothing seems to work on the page and its driving me nutz.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as its parent?

Comment: The iframe works, the scroll to bottom isn't working. It's a jQuery question not an HTML one :) (yes its in the same domain).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With jQuery you need to use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) to access whatever's inside the iframe. You also need to use either the window load event, or the iframe's document ready event.

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    var $contents = $('#frame').contents();
    $contents.scrollTop($contents.height());
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ujuci5/2

---

I would recommend going back to the div structure you mentioned, since it sounds like what you're trying to do doesn't require an iframe. You'll find that it's a lot less headache to work with a div than an iframe.

```
$(function ()
{
  var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');
  $mydiv.scrollTop($mydiv.height());
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ujusa4/2

---

> how can i launch the scroll function like 3 seconds after the page loads?

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout).

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        var $contents = $('#frame').contents();
        $contents.scrollTop($contents.height());
    }, 3000); // ms = 3 sec
});
```

Comment: Thanks but seems like i need to run the function only after 1-2 seconds cause there is a shout box and it takes like 1-2 seconds before it loads so it basically goes down and then the shoutbox loads and its going up again, any suggestions?

Comment: What shoutbox are you using? Ideally you'd be able to pass a callback to the shoutbox which runs after the shoutbox loads.

Comment: Yshout 5. ( <script type="text/javascript">
    new YShout )

Comment: Hm, I can't find any actual API docs for Yshout. If there's an option for it, the setup code would be something like `new YShout({... onLoad: function () {...}, ...});`

Comment: this shoutbox is pretty unstable so i would better implement the idea with the iframe, so how can i launch the scroll function like 3 seconds after the page loads?

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to the source code of the iframe contents, one easy trick is to add an <a name='end'>&nbsp; (or the last line of your content)</a> (not sure if you really need anything in the <a> tag).

Add #end to the iframe source, e.g.

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/file.php#end
```

and it will automatically scroll to the end, no javascript/jquery required

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I think it can be any element (span, div, a, etc) with attribute `id="end"`

Answer (score 1):

If the current document is ready, this means that the DOM is ready, but the document inside the iframe has to be loaded too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#frame").load(function(){this.contentWindow.scrollBy(0,100000)});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the thing i've asked in the comment to Matt Ball, however like i said there is a shoutbox that loads 1-2 seconds after, anyway your code didn't worked too. :\

Comment: So take a look at the YShout-documentation and search if there is a possibility to use a callback-function when the shoutbox has been loaded. If yes, call `window.scrollBy(0,100000)`