# slide to div within the iframe onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having a website that loads a website into an iframe

```
 <iframe src="<?php echo $url ?>" id="exframe"></iframe>
```

what i want to do is in this website there are loads of images on top so once the iframe is loaded i want to slide to the bottom content

within the iframe, the website has the below classes and ids.

```
<div class="images"> </div>
<div id="slider"> </div>
<div class="blocks"> </div>
<div class="content"> </div>
```

i did try below code but it doesn't seem to be working for the elements withing the iframe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').slideDown(1000);
});
```

is there a specific way that i can apply the above code into a iframe?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: @LiveEn give this a shot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316250/how-to-scroll-an-iframe-to-the-bottom-when-page-loads

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access the contents of the iframe **from** the parent, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#exframe").contents().find("body").find(".content").slideDown(1000);
});
```

And if you know they'll be `<div>`s, use this selector: `div.content` to make it more efficient.