# Grab url for div class jump

Tags: html, css, url, href

I want to be able to embed this page https://beta.weather.bom.gov.au/location/r3gx2fe-sydney but specifically jump to the rain radar images byways of URL and a jump?

For the life of me I cannot work out how to jump to that section of the page using an anchor, if all the div sections are named with  and not .

Using https://beta.weather.bom.gov.au/location/r3gx2fe-sydney# doesn't fire and I can't seem to work out how else to do it? The button at the top of the page that says "rain radar" is what I want to fire on load.

I've tried finding the class and ID names, but I can't seem to jump to a class without an ID.

Comment: https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/jump-link-same-page

Comment: Since there are no IDs used you can't use URL hash. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316250/how-to-scroll-an-iframe-to-the-bottom-when-page-loads) could help?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I don't have any control over the embed code, which is the tricky part. I guess I could self host a file with that java script in it?

Comment: But what gets me is the button on the top of the page that says "Rain radar" jumps exactly to the area I want... How are they doing that without id's?

Comment: Inspecting that button, it only has class="RadarLink-ksVuZ jrllfW .. no href or anything...